# Restrict server information

Tags: php, .htaccess

I developed an application using code igniter which is go through security audit.

In security audit they told me that server information should not show and give me screen shot for that

I searched on internet but cant find any solution.

Is there any solution?

Below is the screen shot

[image]

Answer (score 2):

You have to change your apache configuration. In your `apache2.conf` there are 2 options to set.

```
ServerTokens Prod
ServerSignature Off
```

In some distributions it's possible that this options are in another file in a `conf.d` folder.

Comment: I can not modified that file because the website is not on my server, But i already given this solution to them and  i will accept this answer whenever i find it useful, thanks.